# Evaluating performance of a program on VM

Tags: c++, performance, benchmarking

I am running a c++ code on ubuntu( Vmware workstation 9) . Now, basically I have three different functions written in c++. I want to do the comparison of the three on the basis of average number of memeory accesses using valgrind cachegrind. Now, I want to make clear will this effect my comparison that I am running the three functions on Virtual machine rather than the host machine?

Somewhere I read this:

> "If you are comparing results on a VM to results not run on a VM, then
>   no, the results are not credible. On the other hand, if both tests
>   were run in the same environment, they yes, the results are credible.
>   Both tests will be slower inside a VM, but the difference should still
>   be credible."

More details:

I have three application codes written in c++. Each application has a function named,CheckInput(). This CheckInput function is performing a different algorithm in each application. So, I am interested that which app's CheckInput function will do its work in less number of memory accesses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evaluating performance through additional layers of abstraction when the product is aimed at a specific hardware is **rarely** a good idea.

Your virtual machine stack will add a lot of useless header to your applications, and like your quote said: "If you are comparing results on a VM to results not run on a VM, then no, the results are not credible.", you are probably going to get very different results on both environments.

Since Cachegrind is monitoring your CPU caches, the results might differ greatly from what you would on VM, since the hypervisor like VmWare might take its own percent of those caches to run your code.

Comment: Alright but if I am comparing all the three functions on VM then still I can get the idea which one performs better? and the same idea I can get if I run the three function without VM but this time there will be no overhead caused by VM.

Comment: Exactly! You can decide which one of your functions performs the best, as long as they are benchmarked in the same environment.